# Page creation in SharePoint for styling

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout

Should I create page using `"Page From Master"` in master pages in navigation in Sharepoint designer or create a Webpart page or `".aspx"` page in `SharePoint designer` or using `"site Actions"` and attach a master page as suggested in this answer. I need to style the page a lot with html & CSS. Which way should I create this page? which one has less limitations?

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint you have three different entities which builds up a page rendering to the user. First, there is the master page, which controls SharePoint at a general level. You’ll find the foundation scripts and styles which works globally on the entire site (which uses this master page). The master page also has the most control of the outer styles. To make changes to a master page, you should make a copy of an existing master page, such as the Seattle master page or Oslo master page. Never ever change a default out of the box master page for two reasons. You may break SharePoint and can’t find a way back to access SharePoint and you have the potential of bringing everything down (and you’re to blame). Secondly, cumulative updates from Microsoft may change the master page which will overwrite your changes and you’re back to square one in your branding effort. Never ever change a default master page.

[image]

The second entity is the page layout, which typically is used to change the appearance of the same types of pages. If you (for example) have a news feed with several pages, you would want all the news pages to be displayed in the same way. That’s when you change the page layout.

The page itself can have inline styles and scripts, and will only affect the current page. That’s true even if you have two pages using the same page layout. So it all boils down to what you’re trying to accomplish.

Reference: [Overview of the SharePoint 2013 page model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191506.aspx)